# Creating instances of classes at runtime

Tags: c#

1. I have created a class (ConflictingBooking) that contains fields for various information in regards to a specific reservation.
2. I loop through a database and select certain reservations based on certain criteria.
3. I want to create an instance of the class with that selected certain criteria.
4. I then want to add each of those class instances to a List which I will use elsewhere.

Problem I have is at step 3. I want to name the new instance something like "found[i]" where i is incremented for each reservation found:

```
              ConflictingBooking found = new ConflictingBooking();
              found.BookingNumber = conflictingBookingNumber;
              found.BookingStarts = conflictingBookingDT;

              conflictingBookings.Add(found);
```

In the above code, I need to replace 'found' programatically.

Whilst I would appreciate a simple code snippet to follow, I would also like to read some reference so I know what I'm doing :-). I just don't know how to google my problem.

Seems I have not been entirely clear - here is the appropriate code:

```
      dbManager.Open();
      dbManager.ExecuteReader(CommandType.Text, string.Format("SELECT BookingDate, {0} FROM BTable WHERE Court IN {1} AND BookingDate IN ({2})", columns, facilityIDs, bookingDates));
      using (IDataReader rdr = dbManager.DataReader)
      {
        decimal conflictingBookingNumber = 0;
        DateTime conflictingBookingDT;
        object result = null;
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < requestedColumnNames.Count; i++)
          {
            result = dbManager.DataReader[requestedColumnNames[i].ToString()];
            if (result != null)
              conflictingBookingNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(result);

            result = dbManager.DataReader["BookingDate"];
            if (result != null)
              conflictingBookingDT = Convert.ToDateTime(result);

            if (conflictingBookingNumber > 0)
            {
              int next = conflictingBookings.Count + 1;


              ConflictingBooking found = new ConflictingBooking();
              found.BookingNumber = conflictingBookingNumber;
              found.BookingStarts = conflictingBookingDT;

              // conflictingBookings is a List<conflictingBooking>
              conflictingBookings.Add(found);
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Hope that clarifies my problem.

Comment: What exactly do you by 'replace found programatically' ? My understanding is that the chunk of code you provide will be scoped within some sort of an iteration where you will populate your collection. Can you please clarify?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with your code? The `new` operator does exactly that - creates a new instance of a class.
Maybe it would help if you clarify *why* you need to replace 'found' which is a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you are looking for is to put your code in a for loop.  I might be completely misunderstanding you but it seems as if you want to do something like this

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var result in resultSet)
{ 
    ConflictingBooking found = new ConflictingBooking();
    found.BookingNumber = conflictingBookingNumber;
    found.BookingStarts = conflictingBookingDT;
    found.Name = "found["+i++ +"]";

    conflictingBookings.Add(found);
}
```

If that's not what you want please clarify your question

Comment: Thank you - I have ammended my original post to include the 'loop'

Comment: Your answer suggests that I don't need a unique name for the item that is to be added to a List<conlictingBooking>. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the name is scoped within the loop so there is no need for the variable to change names within the loop.  The name is only bound to the object while that iteration of the loop occurs.  With the loop you added to the question I'm not sure what you are asking now

Comment: It seems I have the answer to the question which would have been better posed as "Do the individual items contained within a List<T> need to be named with a variable at all?" The answer is apparently No.
I can obtain all the data I need without a variable name anyhow so it makes a lot of sense to me when I think about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Variable names only exist as a matter of convenience to the programmer, and don't really exist at runtime. You cannot produce actual variables at runtime.

Because you're populating a list, however, you should have all the data required to produce a "name" for display purposes based on the index. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < conflictingBookings.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("found[" + i + "]: " + found.BookingNumber);
}
```

Comment: I thought I needed a unique name to add an instance of a class to the list. Seems this is not the case!

Comment: @David: I see. Variable "scopes" are what you should google, then. In this case, the "found" variable only exists inside the braces on the "if" block.

Comment: Thanks - all makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Add the loop counter to your constructor:

```
ConflictingBooking found = new ConflictingBooking(i);
```

Then add a method (or override `ToString()`) to return the string concatenated instance name.

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if it was a difficult solution for anyone with experience in this case however I have always been able to avoid this situation in the past but thought it was about time I confronted it :-).
Is there any chance of you posting the code that you are suggesting using my example in the question.

Comment: Mitch - I have no idea what you are talking about!